# Why "collect" action in spark triggers data collection to driver?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

When we use  `show` or `take` or  `write`  actions in spark will all the data be sent to driver? If not, then why when we use `collect` does all the data go to driver?

Answer (score 2):

`show` and `take` fetches the amount of data that you requested (e.g. 20 rows) onto the driver, while `collect` fetches the data in the **whole** dataframe, **across all partitions**, onto the driver. `write` will output the whole dataframe to a file location, but it's generally done in a partitioned manner, meaning that each executor can directly write the data contained in its partition to the file system.

Comment: I don't think `write` fetch will the data to the driver - there is no need for it. It would only happen if there is just one partition or you do `coalesce(1)` before. When you write e.g. to HDFS, each executor can directly write it's local partitions to the HDFS filesystem. I mean, it's the same as for reading from HDFS - file splits and partitions will be computed in advance, then assigned to executors, each executor will directly load from HDFS

Comment: Suppose we have a RDD with 10 partitions - doing ```repartition(1)``` or ```coalesce(1)``` and then do a ```write``` will make driver collect all the data and write to ```HDFS```. But what if we do ```repartition(2)``` or ```coalesce(2)``` and then do a ```write```, then will the driver come in picture?? or the data will be shuffled among executors to bring 10 partitions down to 2 partitions??